# return value from python script to shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am new in Python. I am creating a Python script that returns a string "hello world." And I am creating a shell script. I am adding a call from the shell to a Python script.

1. i need to pass arguments from the shell to Python.
2. i need to print the value returned from Python in the shell script.

This is my code:

**shellscript1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# script for testing
clear
echo "............script started............"
sleep 1
python python/pythonScript1.py
exit
```

**pythonScript1.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

print "Starting python script!"
try:
    sys.exit('helloWorld1') 
except:
     sys.exit('helloWorld2')
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can't return message as exit code, only numbers. In bash it can accessible via `$?`. Also you can use `sys.argv` to access code parameters:

```
import sys
if sys.argv[1]=='hi':
    print 'Salaam'
sys.exit(0)
```

in shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script for tesing
clear
echo "............script started............"
sleep 1
result=`python python/pythonScript1.py "hi"`
if [ "$result" == "Salaam" ]; then
    echo "script return correct response"
fi
```

Comment: thanks ali. this code is working fine. but i need to return a string value. how it will be possible?

Comment: you should capture python result: a=\`python python/pythonScript1.py "test"\``; echo $a will print what you print in python code

Comment: In my case, sys.exit(0) doesn't return anything and the shell script stops as well. But print(0) works well. What happens in my case?

Comment: @zhangboyu , I guess you use ' instead of `

Comment: @AliNikneshan I really used `

Comment: @AliNikneshan  I noticed what happened. In shell script I set -e, so it stoped while exit(). Is there any other way to get the value while setting -e?

Answer (score 10):

Pass command line arguments to shell script to Python like this:

```
python script.py $1 $2 $3
```

Print the return code like this:

```
echo $?
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use exit() without sys; one less thing to import. Here's an example:

```
$ python
>>> exit(1)
$ echo $?
1

$ python
>>> exit(0)
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: The exit() is defined in site.py and it works only if the site module is imported so it should be used in the interpreter only.
https://www.scaler.com/topics/exit-in-python/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exit-commands-quit-exit-sys-exit-and-os-_exit/