# Capture return value from python script in command line

Tags: bash

Say I have some python script that looks something like

```
# myscript.py
#!bin/env python

def func(argv):
    <some debugging print messages>
    <some logic>
    return some_string

def main():
    return func(sys.argv)
```

How can I capture the returned string value of this script in a bash script or terminal session (to print to console or use as value in another command)?

Have seen several other similar posts on SO ([return value from python script to shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171568/return-value-from-python-script-to-shell-script), [store return value of a Python script in a bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900828/store-return-value-of-a-python-script-in-a-bash-script)), but these don't appear to account for the fact of needing the intermediate messages to remain in the code (eg. something like

```
#echo "$(myscript.py 'input')"
```

ends up including all of the python script's debug messages along with the return value). Does anyone know what could be done here?

Comment: Do you want to capture this output in a file?

Comment: The script itself cannot return anything other than a single integer called the exit status. There is nothing special about your `main` function; it's return value is not treated specially by the script as a whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the return value (which is unclear in the question) is a single line of output you could simply:

```
./script.py | tail -n 1
```

This will output the last line generated from the script (adjust the number as needed).

If you want to save to a file either `>` to create a new file, or `>>` to append to a file:

```
./script.py | tail -n 1 > file
```

Comment: This is the answer that I ended up using. For others finding this post, but with slightly different situations, some other ways to return values from python scripts can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18231470/8236733.

Comment: Yes, you can use `sys.exit(123)` in python. Then shell will intercept exit code in  `echo $?`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of printing, use the `logging` module. It will print to `stderr` by default and you can redirect that somewhere else... OR disable all debugging output. Take a look at the table at the top of this page for usage advice: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html